# C++: Using dynamic memory allocation to write a function similar to the C realloc() function (i.e. change it's size)

Tags: c++, arrays, dma

I would like to write a function (changeSize) that uses DMA, where I can choose to change it's (an array's) size to whatever I want, where oldEls is the original size, and newEls is the new size. If newEls is larger than oldEls, I would just add zero's to the end, and if it is smaller than oldEls, I would just truncate. The "ptr" parameter needs to point to the new array. It is my understanding that this would be similar to the C realloc() function.

With the code presently below, I am outputting the following: 0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, where the correct output should be 4, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0. I also realize that my show function is maybe not the best function to output the new array, since I have to explicit state the array element size.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void show( const int a[], unsigned elements );
int * copy( const int a[], unsigned els );
void changeSize( int * & ptr, int newEls, int oldEls );
void die(const string & msg);

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = {4, 2, 3, 6};

    show(arr, 4);

    int * newArr = copy(arr, 4);

    cout << endl << endl;

changeSize(newArr, 8, 4);
show(newArr, 8);

}

void show( const int a[], unsigned elements )
{

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;

}

int * copy( const int a[], unsigned els )
{
    int *newArr;

    try
    {
        newArr = new int[els];
    }
    catch(const bad_alloc &)
    {
        die("Copy: Alloc Failure");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < els; i++)
        newArr[i] = a[i];

    return newArr;
}



void changeSize( int * & ptr, int newEls, int oldEls )
{

    int * newArr;

    try
    {

        newArr = new int[newEls];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldEls; i++)
        {
            newArr[i] = ptr[i];
        }

        if (newEls > oldEls)
        {
            for (int k = oldEls; k < newEls; k++)
                newArr[k] = 0;
        }
    }

    catch(const bad_alloc &)
    {
        die("changeSize: Alloc Failure");
    }

    ptr = newArr;
    delete[] newArr;

}


void die(const string & msg)
{

    cerr << "Fatal error: " << msg << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

Comment: Why not use `realloc` directly?  Or use std::vector?

Comment: `realloc` would not ask for the old size, and does not zero the new space.

Comment: http://ideone.com/wSEv2S  Could do something like that.. but I don't see why you want to reinvent the wheel..

Comment: This isn't really the same as `realloc` at all, you're not even attempting to reallocate in place.

Comment: All of this code can be replaced by `std::vector<int>` and calling the `resize()` function.  It is doing everything you're trying to do, but safer and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it's not like realloc() - I should have phrased it differently (i.e. just re-sizing an array). It's been a while since I took my C programming class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of, you call delete on `newArr` at the end of `changeSize`. you need to delete the old value of ptr (that you currently discard). That's (probably) the problem

While I'm at it, I'd like to point your interest to `std::vector`. It's basically a resizeable array.

Also, copying raw chucks of memory is *still* best done with `memcpy`, don't waste your time with writing for loops just to copy `int`s, do that only for C++ classes.

**EDIT**: using `std::copy` is the best solution for C++, it uses `memcpy` when it can, otherwise it's the same as a for loop copying the objects.

Cheers!

Comment: You're right of course I'll edit my post and add that to it. Still memcpy *is* an option - good old C.

Comment: Thank you very much. I apologize for my ignorance on this, but could you clarify regarding deleting the old value of ptr?

Comment: `ptr = newArr; delete[] newArr;` You are deleting the memory you just allocated.